# Query-ing memory in use crashes the app?

Tags: .net, winforms, out-of-memory

At time of this, application was consuming about 150MB of memory.  Look at this:

Exception messsage:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> Stack trace:
>     at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessInfoHelper.GetProcessInfos()
>     at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetProcessInfos(String machineName)
>     at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
>     at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_WorkingSet64()
>     at StreamSink.frmMain.get_MemoryUsed() in C:\Projects\VideoPhill\PlayerRAC\StreamSink\StreamSink\StreamSink\frmMain.cs:line 819
>     at StreamSink.frmMain.CalculateStatistics() in C:\Projects\VideoPhill\PlayerRAC\StreamSink\StreamSink\StreamSink\frmMain.cs:line 803
>     at StreamSink.frmMain._timerUI_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\VideoPhill\PlayerRAC\StreamSink\StreamSink\StreamSink\frmMain.cs:line 736
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)

Well, what is wrong here?

EDIT (more info):

This one fails:

```
    private long MemoryUsed
    {
        get
        {
            return Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024;
        }
    }
```

And is called from:

```
    private void CalculateStatistics()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(CalculateStatistics));
        }
        else
        {
            barStaticItem1.Caption = "Mem: " + MemoryUsed.ToString() + " MB";
        }
    }
```

that is called from timer event, and timer is of type: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

*** Error CAN'T be reproduced on its own. ***

Comment: (Moving this comment to question as I am deleting my answer for now): Hmm, that does look a bit odd. I'm still suspecting the timer may have something to do with it. What happens if you change it so the call isn't triggered by a timer?

Comment: @BrianRasmussen didn't try it, since that one happens every two weeks and only in production.  No chance to provoke it on purpose...

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: Could you please post full repro code (à la http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html)?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu i did.  That method above fails, and is called from the timer, where the value that is obtained is ToString()-ed and set to a label.  Nothing more to it.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: Sorry, but I don't go over 45 with that approach.  Could you please provide a full sample that produces the OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu thank you for your persistance, but as I stated in the comment, I am UNABLE to reproduce that error on purpose.  It comes out in deployed application runtime once every few weeks.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: I meant the complete code for the sample in which you can repro the exception when run from a timer.

Comment: OK, I added more code, but I don't know what part of 'I can NOT reproduce the error by intent' you don't understand? :)

Comment: @Daniel, don't you miss a quote in your sample code: barStaticItem1.Caption = ___QUOTE HERE?___Mem: " + MemoryUsed.ToString() + " MB"; ?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: Sorry, my understanding was that your sample code was from a repro sample, not the production app that was causing the problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I was hoping for some guy with lots of experience with process control or some low level MVP should come and tell me that I have to watch for XYZ if I query the memory in the way I do.  I guess I'm left with a try { stuff } catch {} and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb here and note that there's something fishy about the assumptions being made.  First off, why would you write such code?  Is it actually *common* for the app to run out of memory and *that's* why you want to display memory usage on your UI?  Secondly, how are you sure that the app actually only uses 150 MB if this happens in production but not on your dev machine?

I'll posit that the exception is real and the assumptions are bad.  The process actually ran out of memory.  That this happened inside the code that was designed to warn the user about low memory condition is very ironic.  But certainly not impossible, the native OS function that supplies the info needs a pretty big buffer when a lot of processes are running on the machine.  You should have used the Environment.WorkingSet property instead.

Also quite notable is that getting 150 MB out of WorkingSet and still getting OOM is quite possible.  It is the *wrong* memory statistic.  WorkingSet describes how much RAM you use.  But OOM is triggered when you run out of *virtual memory*.  Two very different measures.  WorkingSet is low when pages of virtual memory get swapped out to the paging file.  Which is highly likely to happen when a lot of processes are running, competing for RAM.

There's no handy property available to measure VM size.  Mostly because it is largely useless, the size of the holes in the memory map is what is important.  You get OOM when there isn't a hole big enough to fit the allocation.  If you want to display a useful statistic then GC.GetTotalMemory() is somewhat useful.  Only somewhat, it doesn't account for unmanaged memory in use.  Solve all your problems by specifying a 64-bit operating system in your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I guess your post is the best explanation of what is going on there, since you guessed correctly that come other app is stealing the memory from innocent only-uses-150-mb app that crashes.  I disagree with some of the statements, but for all I know, you just hit the spot.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing the OutOfMemoryException being thrown from that call stack for the simple reason that the code is run repeatedly (from the timer).  The code that is actually consuming all that memory probably lies elsewhere -- the timer-run code just happens have to bad luck to try to grab more memory when there isn't much left.

If you can't think of any reason why the application should be using so much memory, chances are that you might have a memory leak somewhere.  You might want to consider grabbing a memory profiler like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/index2) to check if this is the case and, if so, where it lies.

Answer (score 0):

Your code really does not show if BeginInvoke has something to do here (since we don't know when InvokeRequired is true).

So obviously this code may be failing, since all the other code looks ok:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024;
```

I suggest you make a small application, which stress-tests Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet. But to be true I doubt it will help (unless your production machine has some hardware problems).

I see you you are using barStaticItem1 - should be a control, isn't it? Well, if you are launching different threads, and this control is not thread safe or is not supposed to be used from other thread (different from the thread which created this control), this may be a source of your problem: 1. occurs rarely; 2. you can't make it occur when you want to.

Comment: We know that InvokeRequired isn't true since we have call stack above, and if it was true, it wouldn't look like that...

Comment: Won't, since pasting code and the whole question sinks deeper and deeper into pointlessness :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason failing was the code was executed repeatedly in background threads, and there weren't any exiting conditions on the recursive call `this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(CalculateStatistics));`

Changing to the following code would help to resolve the problem.

```
private void CalculateStatistics()
    {

        Action showMemoryUsage = () =>
                                     {
                                         barStaticItem1.Caption = "Mem: " + MemoryUsed.ToString() + " MB";
                                     };
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(showMemoryUsage));
        }
        else
        {
            showMemoryUsage();
        }
    }
```